# fabric js : change image url in case of grouped objects

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

see link :http://jsfiddle.net/mishragaurav31/ang58fcL/#base

i make two grouped objects one from two objects (circle and text) and other from two images,

when i want to change attributes of any of group for group 1 it works fine.

but when i want to chnage image src for group 2 it not works.

how to make it works ?..

Html code:

```
    <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas><br>
<a id="cg1">change image</a>
<a id="cg2">change text</a>
```

javascipt code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/benjigarner/softdimension/256/Image-ready-CS-2-icon.png', function(img) {
        var img1 = img.set({ left: 0, top: 0 });
        fabric.Image.fromURL('http://demo-stable-ofbiz.apache.org/images/products/GZ-1000/small.png', function(img) {
            var img2 = img.set({ left: 0, top: 0 });
            var group = new fabric.Group([ img1, img2], { left: 0, top: 0 });
            canvas.add(group)
        });
    });


var comicSansText = new fabric.Text("I'm in Comic Sans", {
  fontFamily: 'Comic Sans'
});

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 100,
  fill: '#942f99',
  scaleY: 0.5,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

var group2 = new fabric.Group([ comicSansText, circle ], {
  left: 150,
  top: 100,
  angle: -10
});

canvas.add(group2);



  document.getElementById('cg1').onclick = function() {
      group.item(1).setAttribute("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0c/IrfanView_Logo.png");
      canvas.renderAll();
  };

  document.getElementById('cg2').onclick = function() {
      group2.item(1).setFill('red');
      canvas.renderAll();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

***You can use .setElement to change the image.***

For example, let's say you have a fabricJS image objects called "myFabricObect".

Then if you have an html image element---, on your page, you can load your myFabricObject with the "newImage" like this:

```
myFabricObject.setElement(document.getElementById("newImage"));
```

You could also new-up a javascript Image() and assign that to myFabricObject:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
myFabricObject.setElement(img);
}
img.src="myNewImage.png";
```

Comment: but i want to change image of one of object in group not image of whole group

Comment: You can take myFabricObject as one of your group object

Comment: yeah done like that see demo link , it works for object but not for image as